# Custom policies in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to make a custom B2C policy in Azure to configure custom identity providers apart from those already supported by Azure AD B2C. That requires some knowledge of how Azure AD B2C understands the xml in those policies.

As I can see, there is a policy base-v1 in every policy, which that policy is referring to. Is there a way by which we can view that policy (base-v1) either through powershell or through any other means ?

Comment: See my asnwer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252795/4167200

Answer (score 2):

Setting up custom identity providers in Azure AD B2C via Advanced policy editing capabilities is currently in private preview and not supported via StackOverflow or any public forum.

***Update***: Custom identity providers are GA for all OIDC providers. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-idp).