# Recommended way to automate deplyoment of Azure AD B2C instance?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

What is the recommended way of automating the configuration of an Azure AD B2C instance, e.g. configuration of policies, application registrations, maybe even creating initial accounts?

- Is it possible to use an ARM Template for it? If so, where can I find a quick-start sample?
- Is it possible to do in a programmatically way, i.e. using PowerShell? If so, where can I find some sample?

Usage scenario: setting up either an ARM Template or Script to deploy (update) to several environments.

Thanks in advance
OliverB

Comment: Its possible to create Custom policies via Power Shell now
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344368/upload-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-via-powershell

Comment: If you use Azure Pipelines you can take a look at this: https://blog.darkloop.com/post/b2c-release-tools-for-azure-devops

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to user an ARM Template? If so, where can I find a quick-start sample?
>   Is it possible to do in a programmatically way, i.e. using PowerShell? If so, where can I find a sample?

Currently, it is not possible to manage B2C policies programmatically. That feature is currently under development.If this is important to you ,you can vote for it [in this Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20342455-programmatically-manage-b2c-policies) so that we can let you know when it is available for preview. The feature request for programmatic registering  application is [in this Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19975480-programmatically-register-b2c-applications).

Additional, If you want get some samples for Azure B2C cutom Plicies, you can refer [these samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, @OliverB , If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer to help more people. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can now use Microsoft Graph apis to manage custom policies and policy keys. Please find the documentation for custom policies api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkpolicy?view=graph-rest-beta) and for policy keys [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkkeyset?view=graph-rest-beta). You can find samples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ActiveDirectory-B2C-MSGraph-PolicyAndKeysets) .

Azure AD B2C supports PowerShell cmdlets for custom policies as of today.

[Azure AD Preview module documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0-preview#trust_framework_policy_management)

[See medium blog](https://blog.medium.com/use-power-shell-to-upload-and-download-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-6fd1786057f1)

Comment: The beta version in Microsoft Graph is in preview.

Answer (score 1):

Until the ability to do this *is* implemented, you just need to document the setup process in detail, with step-by-step instructions, and any scripts you can write (such as power-shell scripts for registering an application with the graph-api).

Keep all these files in a separate module or folder in your project and under version control.

Once it can be automated (if ever), these files can be used as the foundation for the requirements of you auto-deployment-and-update module.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to automate creation of AAD B2C tenant. You can follow this tutorial to create a BC tenant:

[Tutorial: Create an Azure Active Directory B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant).

Since B2C custom policies went GA, there are some new AAD roles that allow some automation:

[image]

If you want to automate upload of custom policies (IEF policy), you can:

1. Create a local user in the B2C Tenant with the `B2C IEF Policy Administrator` role.
2. create a `native` app registration

   [image]
3. Add **Required Permissions** for the previously created application registration

   `Access directory as the signed in user`

   [image]
4. Grant permissions

   [image]

The Graph API (beta version) provides endpoint to manage custom policies:

[trustFrameworkPolicy resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkpolicy?view=graph-rest-beta)

Here is the script I am using to upload custom policies (`Upload-B2C-CustomPolicies.ps1`):

```
Param(
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $b2cTenantName
    , [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $graphAppId
    , [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $userName
    , [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $userPassword
    , [string[]] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $filePaths
)

function Get-Accesstoken {
    param (
        [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $b2cTenantName
        , [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $graphAppId
        , [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $userName
        , [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $userPassword
    )

    $accessTokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$b2cTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token"

    $body = @{
        grant_type = "password"
        resource   = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
        username   = "$username"
        password   = "$userPassword"
        client_id  = "$graphAppId"
    }

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Uri $accessTokenUrl `
        -Method Post `
        -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" `
        -Body $body

    return $response.access_token
}

function Set-Policy {
    param (
        [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $policyUrl
        , [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $accessToken
        , [string] [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $xml
    )

    $headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken";
    }

    Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Uri $policyUrl `
        -Method Put `
        -Headers $headers `
        -ContentType "application/xml" `
        -Body $xml
}

Write-Host "Getting access token to call the graph api"
$accessToken = Get-Accesstoken -b2cTenantName $b2cTenantName -graphAppId $graphAppId -userName $userName -userPassword $userPassword

foreach ($filePath in $filePaths) {    
    try {
        Write-Host "`nGetting file content from file path: $filePath"
        $xml = Get-Content $filePath | Out-String
        [xml]$xmlDoc = $xml
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]$filePath is an invalid xml file."
        return
    }

    $policyId = $xmlDoc.TrustFrameworkPolicy.PolicyId
    $policyUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustframework/policies/$policyId/`$value"

    Write-Host "Uploading policy with id: $policyId"
    Set-Policy -policyUrl $policyUrl -accessToken $accessToken -xml $xml
}
```

I execute the script like this:

```
.\Upload-B2C-CustomPolicies.ps1 `
  -b2cTenantName "my b2c tenant name" `
  -graphAppId "app id of the previously created app registration" `
  -userName "b2c local username with IEF policy admin role" `
  -userPassword "b2c local user password with IEF policy admin role" `
  -filePaths "full path of the TrustFrameworkBase.xml file", "full path of the TrustFrameworkExtension.xml file", "full path of the SignUpSingIn.xml file"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell AzureADPreview 2.0 module to manage custom policies, applications, etc. Although not such a complete thing like ARM Templates, but you can automate many things for now.

Full doc is here: [AzureADPreview 2 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-2.0-preview)

I had no success to install this module to **"old"** PowerShell (5.x) so I gave a shot to the 'new' PowerShell 7 (Core). The only issue with PowerShell 7 and AzureAD module is that `Connect-AzureAD` uses a cryptographic function which is not in .NET Core, so you *must* import the AzureADPreview module using the `-UseWindowsPowerShell` option.

Here is a sample, works with PowerShell 7:

```
Install-Module AzureADPreview
Import-Module AzureADPreview -UseWindowsPowerShell
$tenantId = "yourb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com"

# Note: this will interactively ask your credentials. 
#       If you want to run this unattended, use the -Credential parameter with a PSCredential object with a SecureString
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId

# ready to go 

#list your all custom policies:
Get-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy

# upload a policy:
$policyId = "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase"
$policyFileName "YourTrustFrameworkBase.xml"
Set-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy -Id $policyId -InputFilePath $policyFileName

#list your all apps    
Get-AzureADApplication 

# examine one of you app and get ideas 
$application = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId af46a788-8e55-4301-b2df-xxxxxxxxx 

# create an application
$applicationName = "yourappname"
$application = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName -PublicClient $true etc
```

Comment: This answer is now deprecated since they are sunsetting AzureAD. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/azure-ad-change-management-simplified/ba-p/2967456 

If you have a way of doing this with their new MgGraph powershell module, please update this as I think it would help a lot of people (myself included)