# How to script azure b2c applications creation

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, azure-powershell

I need to create bunch of azure b2c application with powershell scripts.
A powershell script to perform steps described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications
thank you

Comment: Foudn these script that might helps: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADB2C/1.7.282/Content/AzureADB2C.psm1. I've tested the app creation and it is working fine but you should wait for a better using the graph api (which is not available for the moment).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is only possible to manage B2C policies programmatically. Since B2C Custom Policies went GA, it is now possible to create custom policies using PowerShell.

Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252795/10571855

However, the feature request for programmatic app mgmt is [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19975480-programmatically-register-b2c-applications). Please vote for it so that we can let you know when it is available for preview.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell AzureADPreview 2.0 module to create applications.

Full doc is here: [AzureADPreview 2 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-2.0-preview)

I had no success to install this module to **"old"** PowerShell (5.x) so I gave a shot to the 'new' PowerShell 7 (Core). The only issue with PowerShell 7 and AzureAD module is that `Connect-AzureAD` uses a cryptographic function which is not in .NET Core, so you *must* import the AzureADPreview module using the `-UseWindowsPowerShell` option.

Here is a sample, works with PowerShell 7:

```
Install-Module AzureADPreview
Import-Module AzureADPreview -UseWindowsPowerShell
$tenantId = "yourb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com"

# Note: this will interactively ask your credentials. 
#       If you want to run this unattended, use the -Credential parameter with a PSCredential object with a SecureString
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId

# ready to go 

#list your all apps    
Get-AzureADApplication 

# examine one of you app and get ideas 
$application = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId af46a788-8e55-4301-b2df-xxxxxxxxx 

# create and application
$applicationName = "yourappname"
$application = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName -PublicClient $true etc
```

Comment: Using this code not getting any prompt for authentication