# Upload IEF custom policies from Azure DevOps task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-ad-b2c

Anyone know if it's possible to upload custom policies via an Azure DevOps task?

The release pipeline *might* look like this:

- Staging Environment - Deploy from Git to IEF, add suffix *_staging*
- Block pipeline for manual testing
- Prod Environment - Deploy to IEF
  without the *staging* suffix

Comment: Hi Mark, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252795/4167200

Comment: Nice!  Thanks Thomas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible through MS Graph API for [Programmatic access to Custom Policies and Keysets](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ActiveDirectory-B2C-MSGraph-PolicyAndKeysets).

You can use Graph API requests to create, update and delete custom policies. These are Graph API requests so you can integrate these in your pipeline but you need to manage the access token.

Answer (score 1):

The MS Graph API is indeed the way to go. For a complete solution look [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-graph-trustframework-policy).
Details on integrating with a DevOps pipeline are [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-graph-trustframework-policy/blob/master/CICDINSTRUCTIONS.md).

Answer (score 0):

Reference 1. Check this blogpost on [Custom Policies release automation with Azure DevOps](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Azure-AD-B2C-Series-Custom-Policies-Release-Automation-with-Azure-DevOps/)

Reference 2. this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ManishTiwari-Azureb2c.AzureADB2CBuildTask) is available in Azure DevOps marketplace, do the work somewhat similar

Reference 3. Here is [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/deploy-custom-policies-devops) from Azure, Deploy custom policies with Azure Pipelines