# Doing DevOps with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-ad-b2c

Is their any guidance available for devops and release management with IEF custom policies?  I'm interested in a more robust mechanism for uploading policies for testing, then subsequent deployment into production.

Edit:
Unlike the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806509/upload-ief-custom-policies-from-azure-devops-task?noredirect=1#comment100185829_56806509) where I very specifically asked if it's possible to upload IEF custom policies via Azure DevOps task, *this* question is concerned with the general notion of "doing devops with IEF".  I find it hard to believe there is no guidance, lessons learned, best-practices etc around IEF DevOps beyond the instructions for uploading a custom policy with GraphAPI.  Surely I'm not the only one concerned with uploading policies straight into production.  Not sure how to better ask this question than I have.

Comment: Guess you already asked similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806509/upload-ief-custom-policies-from-azure-devops-task.