# Azure MgGraph Powershell Upload Identity Experience Framework Policy

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm working on automating the creation of an Azure AD B2C tenant in Terraform, I can get many parts of it set up in Terraform but some parts I realize I can't, specifically Identity Experience Framework Custom Policies. I decided I would use PowerShell to upload these XML documents. I see that AzureAD is being deprecated [this year](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/azure-ad-change-management-simplified/ba-p/2967456), so I shouldn't use that PowerShell Module. [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) says that we should be using MgGraph now instead of AzureAD, and references the [conversion documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/azuread-msoline-cmdlet-map?view=graph-powershell-1.0#azure-ad) to go from AzureAD to MgGraph. The problem is that the exact functionality I need does not seem to be in MgGraph, specifically functions referenced in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813332/recommended-way-to-automate-deplyoment-of-azure-ad-b2c-instance/56252795#56252795), `Get-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy`, `Set-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy` which is now obsolete. (Referencing the most recent answer).

**QUESTION**
So how do people automate the addition/removal of Custom Policies in Identity Experience Framework in a way that isn't going to be deprecated this year?

I really want to avoid needing to manually create these policies and the associated secrets. It *seems* like it should be straightforward to just upload a document and create a key, so hoping I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: here is a mapping to the graph cmdlets. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/azuread-msoline-cmdlet-map?view=graph-powershell-1.0 your cmdlet have not been migrated yet. so currently you would probably have to use the API directly

Comment: yeah, that's the link I referenced above with the "Conversion documentation" link. When you say "Use the API directly" Can you point me to documentation for that?

Comment: haha sorry ;-) Doku API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0 ... i know azure is fun... think this is what you search for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkpolicy?view=graph-rest-beta - its on the beta version of the api, you can switch to the beta version: select-mgprofile -name beta

Comment: u can use Invoke-MgGraphRequest for the requests

Comment: You are my hero. If you add this as an answer, I will accept it. I have been googling like crazy to find this information exactly but I wasn't able to find it. Thank you

Comment: makes sense to merge this into a answer... nice that I could help you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmdlet mapping AzModule to MgGraph:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/azuread-msoline-cmdlet-map?view=graph-powershell-1.0

MSGraph REST API Docu:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

The API Calls for your specific need:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkpolicy?view=graph-rest-beta

switch to beta api

```
select-mgprofile -name beta
```

cmdlet to interact with the API:

```
invoke-MgGraphRequest
```